# copying with memcpy some data to mmap return pointer address location of a file

Tags: c, mmap

If I have a file which I mapped with `mmap` like this

```
sfd = open("test.txt", O_RDONLY);
filesize = lseek(sfd, 0, 10);
src = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, sfd, 0);
```

so right now the `sizeof` mapping is 0 bytes because size of test.txt is 0. So what if I want to write word `hello` to mapped area. How to do it?

I tried like this

```
memcpy(src,"hello", sizeof("hello"));
```

But this throws Bus error. I could use `mremap` but that is not available on my system. So I like to know how to write to mapped area something with `memcpy`

**Update**

This is my code and now it giving me segFault at `memcpy` line

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){

    int sfd, dfd;
    char *src, *dest;
    size_t filesize=10;

    /* SOURCE */
    sfd = open("test.txt", O_RDWR);

    src = mmap(NULL, filesize, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, sfd, 0);
    ftruncate(sfd,10);
    if(src== MAP_FAILED)
      {printf("error\n");exit(0);}  

    /* DESTINATION */
    memcpy(src,"hello", sizeof("hello"));

    munmap(src, filesize);

    close(sfd);
    close(dfd);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would guess `PROT_READ` and writing to the memory isn't a good thing.

Comment: What is the result of `src== MAP_FAILED`

Comment: How about setting the size of the file to a specific value? For example with `ftruncate`. Of course, that means you have to open the file with writing enabled (e.g. `O_RDWR`).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks for comment. Now its giving me Segfault at memcpy

Comment: @Gerhard yes src is not src== MAP_FAILED

Comment: Well you still have only `PROT_READ`. The memory isn't writable.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh yes ofcource thanks working now